# What would cause ifstream code to fail on OS X?

Tags: c++, macos, file-io

I have the following code

```
string fileName = "assets/maps/main.json";

std::ifstream file(fileName);
std::string temp;

if(!file.good())
{
    LOG(logERROR) << "Failed to open map file: " << fileName;
    //return;
}

LOG(logDEBUG) << "file Char Count: " << file.gcount();

while(std::getline(file, temp))
{
    mapString += temp;
}

file.close();
```

This code works superbly on Windows 8. When I take this program over to OS X, the file fails to open 100% of the time. Or to be more concise, file.good() never returns true. I intentionally commented out the return there to help debugging for later code.

Anyway, this has driven me insane. I cannot figure out why it's failing on OS X. I've tried different directories, re-created the file on OS X to make sure it wasn't an encoding or line-end issue, nothing at all.

What else can I do to debug, or what might I try as an alternative?

I've also checked the file permissions themselves and they are all fine. I have many other types of files in the same directory structure (images, music, fonts) and they all open fine, it's just this JSON file that fails, and any new derivatives of this file also fail.

Comment: Have you tried using the full path to the file?  It's going to look in your (current working directory)/assets/maps/main.json for the file

Comment: Hi, the full path worked... but this is a game that will be installed on peoples computers in a directory of their choosing.. what would be a good strategy to dynamically detect that full path? Will take any other ideas. For the record, I also tried something like ./path/to/file and that didn't work either. And all the other files in my code that I mentioned are accessed with paths similar to the above

Comment: You could run the program from the directory your source tree is in.  A better idea may be to include the path to the game in a configuration file.

Comment: @Jasconius: You should check the working directory settings of your IDE. In production code, unless your program is invoked from command line, the working directory should be the same as the directory your porgram resides in. But an IDE usually change that to its liking.

Comment: Have you produced an app bundle for OSX?

Answer (score 0):

When you start a program on Linux or MacOSX, the working directory will be wherever the user is. So, if your game needs to find files, you need to make use of the appropriate preference system. Mac has a concept of a 'bundle' that allows a program to come with data files and use find them, you'll have to learn how to make one. You can look inside all the '.app' directories in your /Applications directories for many examples.

Comment: I understand this, but why do the 25+ other files in this same directory all read just fine with the same amount of relative path information?